# Form Resizing and Maximizing

Tags: windows, resize, max, maximize

I am preventing the user from resizing the form. How do I also remove the maximize button?

Answer (score 2):

If it is winforms (.net) you are talking about, then right click on the form in the designer and choose properties. Make sure the "MaximizeBox" is turned off in the list of properties.

If it is MFC then look for a property called "Control Box" and turn that off.

Answer (score 2):

First of all... to be able to resize (or not) the FormBorderStyle should be setted to the correct value. To not allow the resize choose one of the options that doesn't say "Resizable".

Then, to remove the control buttons on the top right corner, set the values "MaximizeBox" or "MinimizeBox" to false. You may clear All the top buttons, seting the "ControlBox" to false.

Those are all properties in the Form itself. I'm not so sure about the exact name of the properties...

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You're probably talking about .NET but if not and you are Using the windows API you would specify this when you call CreateWindow. something like this:

```
hwnd = CreateWindow (szAppName, TEXT("Program Name"),
    WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX,
    ...
```

should give you a window that can't be resized. Be specific when u call the method rather than passing something like WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW.